# table parameter variable (basic)

Tags: php

I have variable:
`$default['text']="This is default text";`
and `$other_text['text']="This is other text";`

I would like to choose one of them in function:

```
function insertText($param){
  if(isset($other_text[$param]))
    echo($other_text[$param]); (*)
  else 
    echo($default[$param]); (**)
}
```

if instead of lines (*) and (**) I write something like: `echo("other_text");` and `echo("default_text");`
I always receive second option. That's why I assume there is something wrong with `$var[$param]` construction. How should that look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$default['text']="This is default text";` and `$other_text['text']="This is other text";` are defined outside the function body, then you should declare them as global inside your function:

```
function insertText($param){
  global $default, $other_text;
  if(isset($other_text[$param]))
    echo($other_text[$param]); (*)
  else 
    echo($default[$param]); (**)
}
```

If you don't do that, then the check `isset($other_text[$param])` will always return `false`.